# No prices in woocommerce cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, checkout, woocommerce

Managed to not display prices in my product page.
But does anyone know how to remoce pricing from the cart and checkout?

Or should that all be custom css tweaks? I am looking for a hook but can't find it. It is a website to order stuff and pricing is not availible online.

Hopefully someone can help me out

Answer (score 1):

I've been there! You will need to inspect every price element on the site and then remove then from the theme's php code or turn it's css classes invisible like this:

```
span.price{display: none;}
```